# Upload PDF to server

Tags: java, php, android-intent

I can't find a way to upload a PDF. I searched through and tried so many examples, but they are all for images or videos or sound waves.  I keep getting an error exception, but the log shows me nothing.

I want to upload a **pdf** file from the internal storage to my server using php

```
public int uploadFile (String sourceFileUri){
    String upLoadServerUri = "http://xxxx/uploadfile2.php";
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
        return 0;
    }
    try { // open a URL connection to the Servlet
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

        Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
        if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //tv.setText("File Upload Completed.");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File Upload Complete",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        //close the streams //
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        //dialog.dismiss();
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Upload File to Server Failed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //dialog.dismiss();
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("Exception file to servr", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    //dialog.dismiss();
    return serverResponseCode;
}
```

Php Code

```
<?php
$target_path1 = "uploads/";
/* Add the original filename to our target path.
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path1 = $target_path1 . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) {
    echo "The first file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']).
    " has been uploaded.";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " .$target_path1;
}
?>
```

Log File

Comment: anyone have a response please?